# Preview of images when cursor hovers to different options in a menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an html page with a menu with 4 buttons having different products

Whenever the cursor hovers on each button it must display images of different products

Any example code/link on how to do it will be very helpful

I'm trying to accomplish this in HTML, CSS and JQuery

I've tried using the css `:hover` pseudoselector on the buttons and changing the visibility but it didn't work.

Comment: can you show some example of what you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the ids of both the buttons and the images.

Since we are working with unreleated elements, we can't use the css `hover` pseudoselector. We have to listen for the `mouseover` or `mouseenter` event to determine whenever the cursor is over a button. Similarly, when the cursor leaves that button, we call the `mouseout` or `mouseleave` events.

Here is an example using JavaScript.

```js
var dinosaur1 = document.getElementById("dinosaur1");
var dinosaur2 = document.getElementById("dinosaur2");
var dino1 = document.getElementById("dino1");
var dino2 = document.getElementById("dino2");


dinosaur1.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    dino1.style.visibility = "visible";
});

dinosaur1.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    dino1.style.visibility = "hidden";
});

dinosaur2.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    dino2.style.visibility = "visible";
});

dinosaur2.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    dino2.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

```css
img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

This is even simpler in jQuery because we get to nest events.

```js
$("#dinosaur1").on("mouseover", function() {
  $("#dino1").css({"visibility": "visible"});
}).on("mouseout", function() {
  $("#dino1").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
});

$("#dinosaur2").on("mouseover", function() {
  $("#dino2").css({"visibility": "visible"});
}).on("mouseout", function() {
  $("#dino2").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
});
```

```css
img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="dinosaur1">Dinosaur 1</button>
<button id="dinosaur2">Dinosaur 2</button>

<img height="150" width="150" id="dino1" src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/dinosaurs/images/5/55/T-rex-dinosaur-clip-art-T-Rex-Dinosaur_1.png/revision/latest?cb=20151118162207" />

<img height="150" width="150" id="dino2" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03520/Kunbarrasaurus_3520731b.jpg" />
```

Comment: jQuery can be even simpler at times... `$("#dinosaur1").hover(function(){ $("#dino1").toggleClass("visible"); });` 3 lines vs. 5. Not to say that using `data-*` attributes as selector targets it can even go from total of 10 lines down to (again) 3 (both *dinos*).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I sometimes overcomplicate things